# Keyup event not on inside a form

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to do something simple: using keys to move a character on the screen with Meteor

I got it working using a Collection to store the character's position, but the keyup event is only working inside of a form/input

I'd like to capture the client keypress everywhere.

```
Template.main.events({
  'keyup': function(evt, tmpl){
    evt.preventDefault();

    // Move up
    if(evt.keyCode === 38){
      console.log('Moving up');
    }
);
```

This code only works when the focus in on an input :/

Comment: Try adding the event to the `body` template.

Answer (score 0):

Add events to `Template.body` the [reference](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_body)

```
Template.body.events({
  'keyup': function(evt, tmpl){
  evt.preventDefault();

  // Move up
  if(evt.keyCode === 38){
    console.log('Moving up');
  }
);
```

Or to `$(window)`:

```
var keyupFunc = function(evt){
  if(evt.keyCode === 38){
    console.log('Moving up');
  }
}

Template.main.created = function(){
  $(window).on("keyup", keyupFunc);
}

Template.main.destroyed = function(){
  $(window).off("keyup", keyupFunc);
}
```